# Ksplashqml crash on startup

Tags: kubuntu

I'm on Kubuntu 20.04 and on startup I get this error:

```
We are sorry, ksplashqml closed unexpectedly
```

And I cannot do anythink except show a text mode only shell with <kbd>ctrl+alt+f2</kbd>

How can I fix my system? [image: ksplashqml crash]

Comment: This is happening for me, too, but only one of the two users for the machine. When I tried launching `DISPLAY=:0 plasmashell` I got an error about breeze-dark icons not being found. Not sure if that's related. Sorry I don't have an answer, but I'm hoping the fact that it works for one profile may give somebody an idea.

Comment: It happened to me on Kubuntu 21.10 today, so I suspect some broken package got shipped with updates. I was able to make the workspace partially work by running `DISPLAY:=0 kstart5 plasmashell` from the text mode. Now I am able to use plasma, but some keybinds do not work, so it is certainly only a temporary solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same issue here.
I have read somewhere that it was in connection with use of shell fish.
I do the following test.

- Install fresh kubuntu 21.10 on virtual machine (vmware)
- do full updates
- install shell fish (at this stage all is working)
- change default shell for the user to fish
- disconnect from plasma and reconnect (i have the issue)
- switch to a console alt-ctl-F2 and change back the default shell to bash
- reboot the machine

After change back to bash plasma start without any issue.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. It is a better workaround than starting plasmashell manually. I am sad that I can not use fish as my default shell, but it is better than not being able to run plasma correctly.

Comment: That works perfectly! thanks! I there a way to keep using fish with plasma?

Comment: It's work after i change default shell. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

i got this error if i updating `Kubuntu 20.04 KDE with fish shell`.
restored then by backup and repeated the update bit by bit.

the complete error message: `ksplashqml PID: 1761 Signal: Segmentation fault (11) Time: 20.02.22 09:10:22`

this works for me:

1. select update selected
2. don't update `linux-generic-hwe-20.04`
3. update
4. surprisingly `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` wasn't in the list anymore (I repeated that again because I didn't believe myself at first)
5. reboot.

## Operating System:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-28-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

## Operating System now (27.02.2022)

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-30-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

the same error happens at Laptop (other device) with same configuration (same OS, same shell, same Tool's).

at Laptop i only needed to wait over a week (don't updating anything), then updating again without errors (`20.02.22`).

Answer (score 0):

+1 for this issue. Nothing seems to be working.
Unfortunately for me `DISPLAY=:0 kstart5 plasmashell` didn't help.
I could fix it by switching to MATE desktop however:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

Comment: Yes, it's what I do first (I installed xfce4) but finally @Jeanot solution works perfectly (disable fish shell)

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have enough reputation, I can post an asnwer here.

I opened another question at [Kubuntu Ksplashqml crashed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394269/kubuntu-ksplashqml-crashed) where I posted my solution. Copying from there:

> After some hours of troubleshooting I switched my Display Manager to
> lightdm and suddenly everything worked again. Find out current DM
> with:
>
> systemctl status display-manager
>
> In my case it was sddm. Reconfigure DM to lightdm:
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm

This way you can keep using fish shell and Plasma