# Kubuntu Ksplashqml crashed

Tags: kubuntu, kde, crash, segmentation-fault

This is related to [Ksplashqml crash on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393943/ksplashqml-crash-on-startup)
I dont have enough reputation yet, to post an answer, so i decided to give an answer via my own question...

Yesterday, when i restarted my PC, I got an error Message:
"Ksplashqml closed unexpectedly [...] Segmentation fault [...]". The same error as in the linked

System:
Ubuntu 20.04
KDE-Plasma 5.18.
Fish as default shell

I switched to my Laptop but after some hours, it had the same error.

After some hours of troubleshooting I switched my Display Manager to lightdm and suddenly everything worked again.
Find out current DM with:

`systemctl status display-manager`

In  my case it was sddm.
Reconfigure DM to lightdm:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm`

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by an update of the snapd package. I created [a new issue on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fish/+bug/1961791).

Possible workarounds:

- Use Bash as default shell. Configure your terminal emulator to use Fish.
- Remove snapd package
- Change your config.fish file to fix the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8741#issuecomment-1047820309